# Unable to reproduce UnicodeDecodeError in windows with sample data

Tags: python-3.x, windows, utf-8

I am walking through some code in a [book](https://effectivepython.com/), and it has an example on how `UnicodeDecodeError` may be thrown, when we are trying to read/write binary data from/to a file -- without specifying the encoding, or specifying read/write mode. But I am not able to reproduce the error shown in the book. Why is the file being written with `utf-8` and I think read with `cp1252`?

NOTE: I am on same python version as book.

```
# try to write binary data in write mode
with open('data.bin', 'w') as f:
    f.write(b'\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5')
# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes


# write a file with binary data in write-binary mode
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5')
# written file has UTF-8 encoding


# preferred encoding in my system is different
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
# cp1252


# read file with binary data and is in UTF-8 encoding \
# should fail acc to book, but doesn't
with open ('data.bin','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
# ñòóôõ
# its as if encoding is 'cp1252' by default
# EXPECTED:
# Traceback ...
#     UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in 
#         ➥position 0: invalid continuation byte


# book specifies the encoding to get same result as above 
with open('data.bin', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: This isn't Windows, but here's a demo where the code works exactly as expected: https://ideone.com/T65dd5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is *not* being written as UTF-8. The bug is that `open()` without an explicit `encoding` keyword argument opens the file in the default encoding for your system, and so the file is being read as CP1252.

Apparently the book presupposes that you are on a system where the default system encoding is UTF-8, which is true on every remotely sane modern system which isn't Windows (sorry for the tautology). It would be surprising if this isn't actually explained in the book itself.

Your understanding of UTF-8 is clearly incomplete. There is no way for `\xf1\xf2` to be valid UTF-8. You can inspect the actual UTF-8 encoding of the corresponding code points e.g. with

```py
>>> '\u00f1\u00f2'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb2'
```

Probably now would be a good time to read up on encodings. The [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) has a brief primer and links to more resources, including Joel Spolsky's standand piece [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) For Python, probably also read Ned Batchelder's [*Pragmatic Unicode*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html). Both of these are short enough to read before bed together, or just reserve 45 minutes here and now to perhaps also include some time for experimentation while you read.

Comment: Aaah... So I unknowingly made the wrong assumption that if `utf-8` doesn't accept binary data, neither will `cp1252` (even if its not useful).  My IDE was showing encoding of the written file to be `utf-8` so I assumed its `utf-8`. Thank you for the material!

Comment: Indeed, many legacy encodings will accept more or less random input, resulting in mojibake. UTF-8 is somewhat unusual in that it will reject many byte sequences as invalid.

Comment: @pyeR_biz: cp1252 codes all 256 characters into a byte, so there is no way it know if it is a binary or a real text file. Common UTF explicitly add some guards (for synchronization, so some combination are not valid). Note: encoding of program sources is not the same as encoding at run-time. And the same program may use different encoding (if you are not explicit) between WIndows and nearly all other systems.

Comment: Actually, cp1252 rejects _some_ bytes as invalid, so it won't accept longer sequences of properly random binary data. But this limited example is not one of those cases. (Choosing bytes in the range \x80-\x9f would allow this example to work on many Windows systems, too. Demo: https://ideone.com/odlnVd)